# Is there a better way of chaining async thunks while catching rejections?

Tags: redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

Since a thunk created with `createAsyncThunk` [will always return a resolved promise](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#unwrapping-result-actions). Is there a better way of handling chained thunks than having to add `unwrapResult` each time in order to catch a rejection?

```js
const fetchUsers = createAsyncThunk('users/fetch', myService.fetchUsers);
const updateUser = createAsyncThunk('users/update', myService.updateUser);

export const updateAndFetch = values => async dispatch => {
  const result = await dispatch(updateUser(values));
  const unwrapped = unwrapResult(result); // required to see if first update was rejected
  return dispatch(fetchUsers());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really.

You could also write it like

```js
export const updateAndFetch = values => async dispatch => {
  const result = await dispatch(updateUser(values)).then(unwrapResult);
  return dispatch(fetchUsers());
}
```

or

```js
export const updateAndFetch = values => async dispatch => {
  const result = await dispatch(updateUser(values));
  if (updateUser.fulfilled.match(result)) {
    return dispatch(fetchUsers());
  }
}
```

but at some point you'll have to do that check.